# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive " " in example.com: 3

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi

I have followed this website http://raspberrypihelp.net/tutorials/24-raspberry-pi-webserver to setup the HTTP server nginx on my Raspberry Pi and try to setup a site call **example.com**. But when I run `sudo service nginx restart`, it said

> Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive " " in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:3

Here is the code in **example.com**.

```
    server {

    server_name example.com 192.168.1.88;

    access_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/access.log;

    error_log /srv/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

    root /srv/www/example.com/public/;

    location / {

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/example.com/public$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

    location /phpmyadmin {

        root /usr/share/;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {

            try_files $uri =404;

            root /usr/share/;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_index index.php;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        }

        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {

            root /usr/share/;

        }

    }

    location /phpMyAdmin {

        rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;

    }

}
```

I've used `/usr/sbin/nginx -t -v` to checked that I 'm using nginx/1.2.1. I can go to http:/127.0.0.1 see the default site (/usr/share/nginx/www/index.html) that means it can run the file **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**. I am just following the steps but it can't run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line:

```
server {

listen 192.168.1.88:80; // Add this "listen" with port 80
server_name example.com www.example.com;

# Rest of code
}
```